# how to insert a \0 to a binary file in C

Tags: c, fwrite

I have to insert a bunch of chars to a binary file.

In order to do that I use fwrite. After that, I would like to put a `\0`.

I am not sure how to do it.

```
const unsigned char *my_word; /*my_word has no \0 at the end*/

fwrite(my_word, my_word_length_in_bytes, 1, my_file);
```

Can you please help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following:

```
fputc(0, my_file);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have your buffer my_word alocated with +1, then

```
my_word[my_word_length_in_bytes]=0;
fwrite(my_word, my_word_length_in_bytes+1, 1, my_file);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`fputc('\0', my_file);` will do it for you
```

Answer (score 0):

An old trick is to use an empty null-terminated string

```
fwrite("", 1, 1, my_file);
```

Comment: It's different, but it works. It's more expensive, yes, and `fputc(0,f)` is a better way to do it. But not the end of the world. I gave this answer because I'd done something similar with `pwrite` to write a null character to a given offset.

Comment: Indeed this trick is very useful with file descriptors and `write` or similar interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

You can either concatenate a '\0' character at the end of `word` before you actually write it into your file (best solution imho) or do a second fwrite with a 0x00 byte (which is ASCII code for '\0').